# How to Manage events in my Own Google Calendar through PHP API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I want to create events in my own google Calendar through PHP API.

1. Should I use Google Service Account for that ?
2. I have followed google tutorials, and setup a service account , and
   created code to insert events into my calendar. The code is working
   fine, the events are not appearing on my calendar.
3. It seems using service account, it's sending events to some other calendar belonging to the service account , but not to my own calendar.

*Note: I have a web application, I just want to send some events in to my own google calendar ( not any other user's just my own single calendar).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found so far is that using Service account is the right approach if you want to edit your own google calendar entries through API.
But you need to give permissions to the service account for the calendar you wish to work on using google Calendar settings.

*To give permission to service account, you just need to add the service account email ID (auto generated , when creating a service account) on the google calendar settings page , under "permissions" section.*